# Catalysts and activation energy

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, kinetics, catalysis, reaction-order

Do catalysts increase rate of reaction only by decreasing activation energy? Or can they affect the Arrhenius factor or reaction orders? Like if one catalyst is more effective at increasing rate of reaction than another, does it mean that it's simply decreasing the activation energy more dramatically? Or are there other mechanisms at play?

Comment: They change mechanism completely, along with kinetics.

Comment: does changing the mechanism include changing the reaction order or Arrhenius factor (A) ?